# Finding which component is active in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out which component is active in a list of components.  Here is a sample of what I'm trying to describe:

File: Child.tsx

```
export default forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => {

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
       info() {
          return{
             name: props.clientid + '-something',
             data: {something}
          }
       }
    }));

    return (
        <div data-clientid={props.clientid} data-active={props.active}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
});
```

File: Parent.tsx

```
const [workspacerows, setWorkspaceRows] = React.useState(null);


useEffect(() => {
    let rows =
        accountworkspaces.length > 0 &&
        accountworkspaces.map((item: any, key: number) => {
            return (
                <Child key={key} clientid={item.id} active={item.active}>{item.name}</Child>
            );
        });

    setWorkspaceRows(rows);
}, [accountworkspaces]);


const eventHandler = (evt) => {

}

render (

    <div onClick={eventHandler}>
        {workspacerows}
    </div>
)
```

Output Sample:

```
<div onClick="eventHandler">
    <div data-active="false" data-clientid="1">Apple</div>
    <div data-active="false" data-clientid="2">Orange</div>
    <div data-active="false" data-clientid="3">Plums</div>
    <div data-active="true" data-clientid="4">Grapes</div>
    <div data-active="false" data-clientid="5">Pineapple</div>
</div>
```

So when the OnClick event occurs and calls the function eventHandler, I want to check workspacerows to find out which Child component has data-active equal true, and from there, call the child info() function to get some more information.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to accomplish this and looking for some advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should work with data instead of using `useImperativeHandle`. this hook is the last thing you should try. Avoid it as much as possible.

You don't need the **useEffect**. useEffect execute after the/each render. So the result of the useEffect applies to the next render. Since you set state in the useEffect it triggers another re render cycle which actually causes to render your `{workspacerows}`.

Just do

```
// Parent.tsx
  
return (
    <div className="App" onClick={evtHandler}>
      {accountworkspaces.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Child key={item.id} clientid={item.id} active={item.active}>
            {item.name}
          </Child>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

In react, your UI is sync with your state. Changes to the state updates the UI. That mean, the state represent the current UI. Therefore you can use your state to find the active item.

```
  // Parent.tsx

  const evtHandler = () => {
    const active = accountworkspaces.find(item => item.active === true);

    // Do your work
    // {
    //   name: active.id + '-something',
    //   data: {something}
    // }
  };
```

Your child should only have following code,

```
const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div data-clientid={props.clientid} data-active={props.active}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also don't use array index as the key prop. Instead use an unique key. For example `{itme.id}` is a better option if `id` is unique per each items.

Comment: Would this work if the child component has an input text box as an example and the user changes the data in the browser on only the active child?  Can I get the new entry typed using the same sample you gave?